# Фиксация активного пункта в прокручиваемом списке

Tags: css, html5

Есть меню(вертикальный список, построенный на ul, li). Список достаточно большой, - примерно 100-120 пунктов. Он заключен в контейнер высотой 300пикселей. Все, что не помещается - уходит в скролл. В меню реализована функция определения активного пункта.
 Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы активный пункт был первым в списке? То есть, он оставался бы на своем месте, но скролл прокручивался и определял такой пункт у верхней границы окна.

Простите конечно за сумбур, но не знаю как еще объяснить. К примеру, таким образом организованно меню тегов на сайте htmlbook

Comment: Тут не столько объяснять нужно, сколько привести пример кода (html + css + js). Что там у Вас за функция, которая определяет активный пункт, мы не в курсе. На ruSO присутствуют телепаты, но их редко интересуют такие вопросы, да и заняты они постоянно)

Comment: Да, при загрузке страницы активный пункт меню должен быть в видимой области списка.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, код самый стандартный. Активный пункт определяется скриптом php.

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li> Пункт списка </li>
<li> Пункт списка </li>
<li> Пункт списка </li>
<li> Пункт списка </li>
<li class="current"> Пункт списка </li>
<li> Пункт списка </li>
<li> Пункт списка </li>
<li> Пункт списка </li>
<li> Пункт списка </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

У div высота 300px и overflow:auto

Comment: а зачем тут php?